# zepto´s flickable.js method for window resizing event?

Tags: zepto, flickable

The problem is once I set this function:

```
$('#survey').flickable({segments:num_segments});
```

I can't find the way to reset, destroy it or override it. So if the user flips the tablet or resizes the window of his browser the segment flicks with the wrong width (set on page load).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I run accross the same problem and saw your question, so look inside the code and came up with this solution, it works fine :)

```
function readDeviceOrientation() {                    
    if ($('.carousel-list')) {
      $('.carousel-list').attr('data-segment-px', $('.carousel-container').width());
      $('.carousel-list').flickable('segment', $('.carousel-list').flickable('segment'));
    }
}

window.onorientationchange = readDeviceOrientation
```